# What do these sentences about area and box mean?

Tags: usage, style, non-standard-english

So I read these sentences somewhere, and they completely baffle me. No clue what they mean at all.

> The comment area is for comments related to improving the quality of the question. The answer box is where to put the answer to the question.

Can anybody help?

Comment: "So I read these sentences somewhere,"   Where exactly !!!  Did you quote them so well from memory but have forgotten the source.  This looks like it is taken from *this very site* so it should be easy for you to say exactly where you read them.

Comment: @JamesK My next question is going to ask the meaning of irony, sarcasm, self-reference, and fourth-wall.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, there are two input boxes on the screen. One is labeled something like **Comments** and the other is labeled something like **Answer** (or perhaps not labeled at all).

The box labeled **Comments** is for you to type in comments that will help improve the question itself (for example, improve clarity).

The box labeled **Answer** is for you to type in the answer to the question.